# A question on notation $\theta (Z)$

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, terminology, smooth-manifolds

The notation $\theta(Z)$  is  frequently used in the  book "Geometry  of  foliation"  by Philippe Tondeur. For  example  in page $9$ [Proposition 2.2.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8DZZSsa14ncC&lpg=PA71&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) ($Z$  is  a  vector  field). I  did  not  find  any  definition in the  book. It is  not appeared   in the "Index of  notation" of the book.

What  is its  definition?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the Lie derivative. I had to look at his earlier book, *Foliations on Riemannian Manifolds*, where the author explains his notation. Some older material appears to have been simply copy-pasted directly into the new book, so I'd suggest having a look at the older reference whenever confusion arises.

> [image]

Comment: Is it the  Lie  derivative  $L_z$? that  is  $\theta (Z)=L_Z$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks a  lot  for  your help.